# Remove an array of words from given string in the most efficient way

Tags: javascript

I want the most efficient (in case of speed) solution to remove array of given words from the given string:

So far I have this not working solution:

```js
const excludeWordList = ['the', 'in', 'a', 'an'];

run("the wall into")
run("paintings covered the wall another words into this")

function run(speech) {

    for(let a = 0; a < excludeWordList.length; a++) {
        speech = speech.replaceAll(excludeWordList[a], '');
    }
    console.log(speech);
}
```

As you see the code has three major issues:

1. It removes characters inside the words not just the single words
2. The result is not a trimmed string we have extra spaces inside words of the result too
3. The code is not the most efficient way ***I think!!!***, because I need to loop through all the `excludeWordList` array.

I wrote my function as `my` and as you see the `Gainza` function is the most efficient function in this case:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const excludeWordList = ['the', 'in', 'a', 'an'];

run("the wall into")
run("paintings covered the wall another words into this")

function run(speech) {

    const result = speech.split(' ').filter(word=>!excludeWordList.includes(word)).join(' ')
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: If the word list is large, it would be more efficient to convert it to a `Set` first, to avoid all the sequential searching in `includes`

Comment: Agree w/ @Barmar. This `includes` is "heavy" on long lists an won't query in `O(1)`

Comment: His solution has the best performance why?

Comment: I used for loop in my solution and our solution is very similar, you used filter but your solution is doing better almost every time. I thought for loop has far better performance than filter method Am I wrong???

Comment: @SaraRee It took 2 years but today I can answer, my code is faster thanks to functional programming, since in a for loop you are occupying more memory space than an anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the a filter & set approach to minimize computation time (instead of `includes` or `indexOf` that iterate the whole array)

```js
const excluded = new Set(['the', 'in', 'a', 'an']);


function run(speech) {
    return speech.split(' ')
           .filter(word => !excluded.has(word))
           .join(' ');
}


run("the wall into")
run("paintings covered the wall another words into this")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that doesn't loop, replaces all excluded words with a single regex, and finished up with a trim and extra space cleanup. This should be the fasted method. You can `map` the array into a Regex and preserve word boundaries `\b`, which have to be escaped when building it dynamically

```js
const excludeWordList = ['the', 'in', 'a', 'an'];
const reg = new RegExp(excludeWordList.map(w => `\\b${w}\\b`).join('|'), 'g')

run("the wall into")
run("paintings covered the wall another words into this")

function run(speech) {
  speech = speech.replaceAll(reg, '').trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
  console.log(speech);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using split() and filter().

**Edit:** `indexOf()` complexity is O(N) because of linear search. Since we have a fixed set of words we want to exclude, converting to a set is ideal.

`new Set()` is also O(N), but since it is being done only once and your `run()` will be called more often it makes sense here. With set, `.has()` has O(1) complexity.

```js
const excludeWordList = ['the', 'in', 'a', 'an'];

const excludeWordSet = new Set(excludeWordList);

run("the wall into")
run("paintings covered the wall another words into this")

function run(speech) {
speech = speech.split(' ').filter((a) => {
return (!excludeWordSet.has(a))
}).join(' ');
  
console.log(speech);
}
```

`filter()` still has O(N) complexity. `join()` has O(N). so this is still O(N^2), same as your initial attempt.

Comment: `indexOf` is the same as `includes` and will consume much time on large sets

Comment: Thanks for that. Using set now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a solution using whitespaces as word separator is that it will most likely fail when you use punctuation for example e.g.

```
'the, Beattles'.split(' ').includes('the')
//=> false
```

Instead you should use `\b` (word boundary):

```js
const excludes = ['the', 'in', 'a', 'an'];
const re = new RegExp('\\b(?:'+excludes.join('|')+')\\b', 'g');

console.log("the.wall.into".replace(re, ''));
console.log("paintings covered the, wall another words into this".replace(re, ''));
```